# Increasing network load in HDFS traffic with stream jobs and Kafka

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, apache-kafka, hdfs, amazon-emr

We experience unexplained behaviour with our new EMR setup that includes:
EMR 5.16 (3 nodes - c4.8xlarge and 1 master - c4.8xlarge)
Kafka Cluster based on ECS

We running simple stream job that reads from a Kafka topic, makes some logic and writeStream back to Kafka topic (using checkpointLocation as HDFS path)

The "problem" is that in Ganglia I can see increasing network traffic that came out from the driver (that runs on one of the slaves) to the Master server.

I can see from a simple pcap file that's the traffic belongs to 50010 (Hadoop Data Transfer) and here I'm in a dead end.

Some help needed, thanks!

[image: Network traffic in EMR Cluster]

Comment: If you are reading from Kafka, and writing back to Kafka, is there a reason you're not using Kafka Streams API? Then you wouldn't need HDFS checkpoints

Comment: This is my code for writeStream for example:

`tmp = host_NoClass \
    .selectExpr("CAST(timestamp AS STRING) AS key", "to_json(struct(*)) AS value") \
    .writeStream \
    .format("kafka") \
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafka_ip) \
    .option("topic", "dd_no") \
    .option("checkpointLocation", chckpt_dd_no) \
    .outputMode("append") \
    .start()`

Do you have any other example for doing this?

Comment: Yes, you're using Spark. Kafka Streams is a different API and does not rely on HDFS or Spark https://kafka.apache.org/11/documentation/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html#writing-streams-back-to-kafka

Answer (score 0):

After some investigation and view the payload of the traffic, it was the logs that sent to the Master! It was delivered to Spark history server and located in HDFS..

I just needed to add this config to my spark-submit `--conf spark.eventLog.enabled=false`